# Using jQuery .hide() with fading

Tags: jquery, hide, fade

I have a `.hide()` function that hides divs based on checkboxes.

[JS Fiddle of it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9ZVk/5/)
[Real site example here](http://www.haselden.co.uk/rttest/inner.html)

I'm trying to give it animation so that the `.hide()` will fade in/out rather than just disappear.

Tried utilising the jQuery Fade function but as a parameter for `.hide()` but doesn't seem to work

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("fade", {}, 1000);
});
```

I tried using this in my code (see JS Fiddle) as the following:

```
if(allSelected.length > 0){
            $("div.prodGrid > div:not(" + allSelected + ")").hide("fade", {}, 1000);
        }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The important thing to note here is that the `hide()` method does not take an effect argument at all. Read [the method's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to see the different arguments. In such methods the first argument or argument property is usually the `duration` argument.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).fadeOut(1000);
})
```

There are also `fadeIn` and `fadeToggle`.

Comment: this thumb up was for jquery

Comment: this technically doesn't answer the question, since show and hide work on display and the fade methods work on opacity.

Answer (score 24):

You might use @Arnelle's solution if you want to fadeOut or

replace `$(this).hide("fade", {}, 1000);`
with

```
     $(this).hide("slow");//or $(this).hide(1000);
```

passing "slow" will give a nice animation before hiding your div.

Modified your fiddle with changes: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9ZVk/8/

Comment: Arnelle's answer fades out. Animation with hide and show is different than fading out... It's cooler than fading out and fading in

Comment: This is really great, however it doesn't work when the filters are clicked in quick succession, quite typical with e-commerce. Think a simple fade might work better. This is great though!

Comment: What a gem! Can't believe I never new this!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `fadeout` with duration instead of using hide.

```
   if(allSelected.length > 0){
        $("div.prodGrid > div:not(" + allSelected + ")").fadeOut(1000);
    }
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9ZVk/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the code in the below link, Its working fine.

[Using jQuery .hide() and .show() with fading -  **Live Demo**](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/JQuery/JQuery/Fade-SlideEffects.aspx?id=53)

```
 $("#btnHideShow").click(function () {
            if ($("#btnHideShow").val() == "Hide") {
                $("#imgHideShow").hide(1000);
                $("#btnHideShow").attr("value", "Show");
            }
            else {
                $("#imgHideShow").show(1000);
                $("#btnHideShow").attr("value", "Hide");
            }
        });
```

You can also find **fadeIn,fadeOut,slideUp and slideDown** Using Jquery from thebelow link.

[fadeIn fadeOut and slideUp slideDown Effects Using Jquery](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/JQuery/JQuery/Fade-SlideEffects.aspx?id=53)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to **hide/Show the div with fading effect for smooth transition** can be achieve by combination of CSS ,jQuery with adding and removing class.

```js
$("#div1").addClass('fade in show').removeClass('in hidden');
$("#div2").removeClass('fade in show').addClass('in hidden');
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}

    .fade.in {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```